# How take exact 15characters using jsonata

Tags: jsonata

Json:
{
"Data":"12345678"
}
I need the result like this
"Data": "12345678     "
Must take 15char
Please help me to write jsonata logic

Comment: Please give more clarification with example.

Answer (score 2):

[$pad](https://docs.jsonata.org/string-functions#pad) function will be useful here:

```
{
  "Data": $pad(Data, 15)
}
```

You can check out this solution in Stedi's JSONata Playground: https://stedi.link/OM1K6XB

Comment: Pad function  is working fine but i need exact characters for example I need 10char only but my json is 15characters but i need only 10charaters if i use pad function it is taking whatever the json comes please help on that

Comment: I see, in that case I believe this is what you're looking for:

`"Data": $substring(Data, 0, 15)`

https://stedi.link/MukARfR